# Operation not permitted with sudo chown on mac

Tags: laravel, xampp, permission-denied

I got this error and I have tried to follow many instructions but it didn't work. Please help me,thanks!
I have run `php artisan migrate` and then I got this :

```
UnexpectedValueException 

  The stream or file "/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I trying with `sudo` but I got 
`"Operation not permitted"`

```
$ sudo chown -R www:www storage
Password:
chown: storage/app/public/.gitignore: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/app/public: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/app/.gitignore: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/app: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/oauth-private.key: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/logs/laravel.log: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/logs/.gitignore: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/logs: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/sessions/.gitignore: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/sessions: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/cache/data/cc/c4/ccc4da08b14ef486fe32b15c805b5e95c7f3122b: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/cache/data/cc/c4: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/cache/data/cc: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/cache/data/38/69/386948609bc3c4027c0048b9ef1c7e61d23cf80a: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/cache/data/38/69: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/cache/data/38: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/cache/data/.gitignore: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/cache/data: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/cache/.gitignore: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/cache: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/views/a49dd52a70c9462f11ab6afe053e3413ed2600cf.php: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/views/ff9e533ffd309c883ff47b05a9b2849d3b9947cc.php: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/views/.gitignore: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/views: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/testing/.gitignore: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/testing: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework/.gitignore: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/framework: Operation not permitted
chown: storage/oauth-public.key: Operation not permitted
chown: storage: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Try this if you are on centos `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t $SITE_PATH`
 
`chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t $SITE_PATH`